# Will automated workers clear forest if I'm playing as Iroquois?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

While playing a game of Civ 5 as the [Iroquois](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Iroquois_%28Civ5%29), I noticed my automated workers were sometimes clearing a forest.  Since the Iroquois get special benefits from forest squares (like the [Longhouse](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Longhouse_%28Civ5%29)), this struck me as counterproductive.

Are automated workers smart enough to maintain forests when playing as Iroquois?

Comment: There might be a setting for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting in the game options called "automated workers remove features". You can turn it off and they will never remove forests.

Comment: Seems both my questions were related to the same setting; thanks!  I'd hoped they would be smart enough to know that Iroquois get benefits from forests and to leave them in place, but perhaps my hopes were too high..

Comment: @toast, actually they are two separate settings. One prevents the removal of natural features like forests, marshes, and jungles. The other prevents the removal of improvements. They are located right next to each other. As far as worker AI being intelligent... we can always dream